# Ansible populating a variable based on a json param with a json param

Tags: cisco, ansible, interface, ios

I have a variable containing json:

```
{
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_network_resources": {
            "interfaces": [
                {
                    "description": "*** - LOCAL A - ***",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "name": "FastEthernet0"
                },
                {
                    "description": "*** - LOCAL B - ***",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "name": "GigabitEthernet1/0/1"
                },
                {
                    "description": "*** - LOCAL C - ***",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "name": "FastEthernet1"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to populate a variable with the name of the interface when the description contains a certain word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**Populate a variable with the name of the interface when the description contains a certain word.**"*

A: For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ ansible_facts.ansible_network_resources.interfaces|
                   selectattr('description', 'search', pattern)|
                   map(attribute='name')|
                   list }}"
      vars:
        pattern: "LOCAL A"
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
  - FastEthernet0
```

and

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ ansible_facts.ansible_network_resources.interfaces|
                    selectattr('description', 'search', pattern)|
                    map(attribute='name')|
                    list }}"
      vars:
        pattern: "LOCAL"
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
  - FastEthernet0
  - GigabitEthernet1/0/1
  - FastEthernet1
```